# Insert string containing forward slashes in specific line using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to insert a string that contains forward slashes into a specific line of a file.

The string I want to insert in line 52 of the file is:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
CUSTOM VARS & MIXINS
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
@import "custom/custom_vars_mixins";
```

Trying to piece together different answers to both questions, I arrived at the following code:

```
sed -i 's#52i
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
CUSTOM VARS & MIXINS
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
@import "custom/custom_vars_mixins";#replace#g' ../style.scss
```

Which returns the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

Can anyone please help with the syntax?

Comment: You need to escape the newlines with backslash.

Comment: Read the `man page` instead of *piece together answers on SO*.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with forward slashes, the problem is that the string contains newlines.

Comment: You solved the problem of forward slashes by using `#` as the delimiter instead.

Comment: @Barmar The problem is that the syntax is incorrect! Please stop leaving confusing comments. If you are unsure: Don't comment. If you realize the comment was wrong: Delete it!

Comment: Wait a second? Inserting a line is done with the `i` command, not `s`. Why do you have `s#52i` in there? There's no `52i` in the input file.

Comment: `s#foo#bar#` is for replacing `foo` with `bar` in a line.

Comment: I stated my goal, and how I went about trying to acheive it. If it is wrong, I'm  asking about a correct way to accomplish it. Fair play?

Comment: What I want to say is that if you have a look at the sed man page or manual you will be much more effecient than *piecing together* wrong stuff from somewhere. The sed man page is not so big and sed is a simple command. Your question appears (for somebody who read the manual) like: I'm hitting the break of my car but it doesn't move forward... On the other hand, I would suggest to use awk: `awk 'NR==53{print "YOUR_STRING"}1' file`

Comment: It should be `NR==52`, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
sed -i '52i\
/*--------------------------------------------------------------\
CUSTOM VARS & MIXINS\
--------------------------------------------------------------*/\
@import "custom/custom_vars_mixins";' ../style.scss
```

Comment: thank you. works on linux, but syntax for mac os x sed is slighty different. made a gist for future reference: https://gist.github.com/brnrds/8dfc8423f27f12aa123aa845c2a3a5a7